# Issue with Add XY Data tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

When I try to add lat/lon data using the Add XY Data tool, I am not given the choice of selecting my latitude and longitude fields but rather Field 1, 2, 3, etc. I have used the Add XY Data tool regularly so am familiar with the small formatting issues required to successfully import data. I recently upgraded to 10.2.

[image]

---

The columns all have appropriate headers: Name (first column), Latitude, (2nd column), Longitude, Z, etc. As I mentioned I have used the Add XY Data tool regularly so am familiar with the formatting issues required to successfully import data. The first option as a field to select is Field18 (as seen in screenshot), which makes no sense. I selected field 19 and 20 for lat and long but this did not work. I believe this is an issue with the tool itself. I am not sure. Anyone have a fix?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your text file has headers for each column, then open your text file and count out which column(area) is where your lat/long data is located in the file. Then select the appropriate column for lat/long.

Answer (score 0):

Check the field names of all the fields before and after Latitude and Longitude to see if there are any reserved words, special characters, blanks or anything. Open the text file in a text editor. Is your file comma delimited or something else?

I have also seen this issue before where the headers are replaced by Field1, Field2, etc. Click on Layer Properties, Source, Set Data Source and select the Drop down. There seems to be two listings for my text file.
[image: Screenshot of Add XY Data]